# Klein bottle, which loop corresponds to the action $h(x,y)=(-x,y+1)$ on $R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let K be the Klein bottle. Then its universal cover is $R^2$, deck transformation group is G generated by actions $g(x,y)=(x+1,y)$ and $h(x,y)=(-x,y+1)$. So
$$
G=\{g,h|h^{-1}ghg(x,y)=(x,y)\}
$$
It's isomorphic to the fundamental group of K.

On the other hand, if you see the picture, beginning at $(0,0)$, counter clockwise, we know that the loop $aba^{-1}b$ is homotopy trivial. Suppose that  $h_a,h_b\in G$ correspoingd to a,b.  then by homotopy lifting property,
$$
h_bh_a^{-1}h_bh_a(x,y)=(x,y).
$$
Since $g(x,y)=g(x+1,y)$ and $h_a(0,0)=(1,0)$, I think $h_a$ is just g. Since $h_b(x,y)=(-x,y+1)$ and $h_b(0,0)=(0,1)$, I think $h_b$ is just h. Then
$$
(x,y+2)=hg^{-1}hg(x,y)=h_bh_a^{-1}h_bh_a(x,y)=(x,y).
$$
Contradiction.
Can someone point out where the argument fails. [image: picture]